# Google Apps Script basic authentication

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, basic-authentication

I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to programming. I've been trying to import data table from "http://www.rotowire.com/daily/nba/value-report.htm" into google spreadsheets.

I came across Google Apps Scripts and urlfetchapp basic authentication and tried to create and run a script but I can't figure it out. This is the code I tried using to for the basic authentication ([came across here][1]):

```
function myTest() {
      
var USERNAME = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('johndoe22');   
var PASSWORD = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('doejohn11');
var url = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('http://www.rotowire.com/daily/nba/value-report.htm');
}
```

Nothing happens when I run this script, what am I doing wrong? I just need the script to be able to pull info from that website.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: The code you provided is just three variables - is there anything else?

Comment: I got the code here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546255/how-to-use-urlfetchapp-with-credentials-google-scripts>;, I think I'm missing some parts to the code tho, any help.

Comment: The properties service is a storage feature.  It stores data in "key/value" pairs.  For your line of code with the variable `url`, you have entered a url where the "key" name is needed.  I'm assuming that you want the url to be the **value** and not the **key**.  In order to *get* a property, you needed to have *set* a property.  Did you set a property with a key name of:  `http://www.rotowire.com/daily/nba/value-report.htm`.  Normally, you'd set a property with a key name of something like 'dataURL', and then the value would be the actual url.  `setProperty('dataURL','http://www.domain.com')`

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to import the table from that website, you don't need Google Apps Scripts - you can do that with the built in spreadsheet function "IMPORTHTML":

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://www.rotowire.com/daily/nba/value-report.htm","table","1")
```

You can read more about the function in the [Google spreadsheet function list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339). I made a spreadsheet using this that you [can view](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w6a4BYatfyF6tF9dzCkjDMG5lX3qe4ypowb5DhSMNNI/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the reason I'm using google app script is so that I can get past the authentication and get the whole table. There are more than twelve players but I can get the whole table without login in. I tried login in and them importing but it didn't work @Jens Astrup