# How to do NTLM authentication in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-apps-script, ntlm, urlfetch

I'm trying to write a script that fetches a bunch of URLs using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)), and they require NTLM authentication. But I haven't got a clue how to go about doing that and the only things I could find with Google are general descriptions of what NTLM is and how it works.

I need an example of how one would go about doing NTLM auth in actual code, preferably in Google Apps Script as it's the environment where I'm trying to achieve this. For example, [this page was great in showing how to do Basic authentication.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546255/how-to-use-urlfetchapp-with-credentials-google-scripts) I was hoping I could find something similar with NTLM, but so far I've had no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for this subject for about a month, and discovered:

- at this moment NTLM authentication is **not implemented** in google script
- even if you write NTLM hashing/encoding/handshaking/... process yourself using gscript it will fail, because *urlFetchApp* method **cannot keep-alive** http connection (keep it opened) for consecutive http request/responses required for NTLM authentification

If you find that something changed on a subject, please inform us!
Best wishes