# Error 401 when connecting to external API Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'am trying to retrieve some data from Klipfolio and put it in a Google Spreadsheet. I'am using Google Apps Script to accomplish this, but I get this error:

> Errorcode: 401.
>   {"meta:{"success":false,"status":401,"error_code":"auth_not_provided","error_desc":"This
>   operation requires authentication"}}

this is my code:

```
function output() {
  var url = "https://app.klipfolio.com/api/1.0/klips/db88d343e7eeef916f9541d73f0df58c/schema/";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  return data;
}
```

I hope you can help me...

Comment: Well, based on that "authentication failure" error, you need to send authentication. Your request shows no special headers, so I suggest reviewing your API documentation and then reviewing the Apps Script documentation for `UrlFetchApp` to determine how you can send it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use your klipfolio username and password in your request.  Here is a StackOverflow post detailing how to do that:

[How to use UrlFetchApp with credentials? Google Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546255/how-to-use-urlfetchapp-with-credentials-google-scripts)