# Google App Script: Authentication failing on UrlFetchApp.Fetch()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch

My code:

```
var username = "";
var password = "";
var options = {};
options.headers = {
  "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password)
};
var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.4for4.com/fantasy-football/full-impact/cheatsheet/Flex/38351/ff_nflstats/adp_blend", options).getContentText();
Logger.log(html);
```

I read through a few posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546255/how-to-use-urlfetchapp-with-credentials-google-scripts) but still having trouble getting the data I need. The result is HTML from the redirected login page. Is it possible this site uses a different Authorization type or do I need to pass something else in the header?

Comment: When you contacted the site about programmatic access to their data, what did they say? If anyone knows how to authorize, it would be the actual website team..

Comment: I didn't contact them yet but I will if needed.

Comment: http`s` The site doesn't use basic authentication. Only old http sites use the authentication you're trying.

Comment: Which should I try...

Comment: Depends.... Do they provide api access? If so, Its straight from the api documentation. If not, I'm not sure ... It maybe oAuth 2, which means you might  need to send a ``Bearer: access token``.... It's better to just contact them...